# Im doing a 2d animation and need timeline help

Tags: animation, grease-pencil, layers, timeline, 2d

I was doing a 2d animation and all was fine till i maybe hit a hotkey or pressed a wrong button. I used to be able to see my layers on the bottom left in my timeline (the default 2d-animation settings) but now theyre gone. I have a lot of progress sunk into this file so I'd be a shame if I had to start over. Please let me know how to fix this, My guess is that its probably a hotkey I pressed but y[image]our guess is probably better than mine. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Simply click on the left top icon in your timeline area (currently that is **graph editor**) and select **dope sheet**

[image]

Comment: oh god thank you sm

Comment: you are welcome if this solves your problem.. would you mind if you please select the answer as accepted?